# How to remove one reducer from redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've inherited a project that uses redux-persist and has multiple reducers. I wrote a new reducer for a small functionality and persisting that reducer is causing problems. It should behave as it would without redux-persist.

How can I ommit one reducer from persisting? Or, if I cannot, how can I manually purge it? In the docs, here: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist , I found this:

```
persistor object
  the persistor object is returned by persistStore with the following methods:
    .purge(keys)
      keys array An array of keys to be purged from storage. If not provided all keys will be purged.
    ...
```

So, this is probably what I need but I don't know where and how to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `blacklist` parameter to give to `react-persist` a list of reducers that should not be stored. So if `do-not-store` is the key of the reducer you do not want to be stored, use :

```
const persistConfig = {
  blacklist: ['do-not-store'],
  ...
}

persistStore(store, persistConfig)
```

Comment: if you were to blacklist a reducer that was previously not blacklisted, would that reducers state be purged?